# Sendmail doesn't obey .forward files? [ ~root/.forward ]

Tags: sendmail, email-server

I am seeing a strange behavior with sendmail, maybe I am missing something?

First, sendmail doesn't understand the local machine's own hostname, despite it being in /etc/mail/local-host-names

It tries to open an external connection to the local mail anyway (and fails since the inbound port isn't open).

Secondly it doesn't see/obey the `.forward` file for root, again it's trying to contact it's own machine without realizing it could handle the whole process by just looking at the aliases inside  `/root/.forward`

I solved this by just adding the `.forward` contents for root to `/etc/newaliases` and running  `newaliases`

But it bothers me it didn't just figure it out both the localhost and the root `.forward` and now there are two places to maintain the addresses.

Are these sendmail limitations? Is it considered outdated? Should I be using postfix instead?

Answer (score 0):

**sendmail doesn't understand the local machine's own hostname**

Q1: Is the hostname on the list of local email domains?
As root execute:

```
echo '$=w' | /usr/sbin/sendmai
```

A1: YES =>
Have restarted (or HUPed) sendmail daemon after modifying `etc/mail/local-host-names`?
It is required.

**Sendmail doesn't see/obey the .forward for root**

For security reasons it is **STRONGLY** advised to alias root (in `/etc/mail/aliases`)to a non privileged user. Sendmail should not even try to process ~root/.forward file. Do you have problems with forward file of a non privileged user?